# How should I connect my light with two cables in the box?

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture

I have been searching far and wide for video tutorials for how to install a pendant light when there are 2 set of ground, black, and white wires coming out the ceiling box. Is this a new type of setup when wiring up the pendant light are you just supposed to cap all the matching colors together?

One set of wires is hot when the flip is switch while the other does not read any power.

[image]

Comment: One choice is the second set of wires power another light from this box/switch.  Power seems to come from the switch, so a switch loop is not used.  Can leave the second set as is and just connect up the hot wires to the light.  Make sure the switch is not a three way with a second switch also controlling the light.

Comment: Rick, this is about as fundamental as it gets. I strongly suggest you do a little reading on house wiring so you don't do something dangerous. You should at least know how to determine which cable has power and whether one runs to the switch.

Comment: @isherwood  OP said one set became hot when the switch was flipped.

Comment: See [End Line Switches](https://www.bhg.com/home-improvement/electrical/switch-wiring/), which are by no means a new type of setup--they're about as old as house wiring itself. (The diagram is unintuitively _before_ the related section.)

Comment: What was there before?